# Explicitation of an isomorphism between two rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I want to show that 
$$\mathbb{Z}_3[\sqrt{-5}] /\langle 3, 2 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle  \cong  \mathbb{Z}_3$$
What bijective map should I build to show the isomorphism relation?

**Important Edit** : I made a mistake. I meant $\langle 3, 2 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ not $\langle 2 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]/\langle 2+\sqrt{-5} \rangle$. And this is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @MooS I believeit is $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @MooS I made some changes in the question. There was a (killer) typo.

Comment: There is still another typo...

Answer (score 3):

Dividing out by $(2+\sqrt{-5})$ means we "set" $2+\sqrt{-5}=0$, or in other words $\sqrt{-5}=1$. What do you think the isomorphism will be?

Comment: Nitpick:  I think you want to say "modding out by" rather than "dividing out by."

Comment: $a + b \sqrt{-5} + \langle 2 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle  \to a + b $?

Comment: I highly doubt that it should be $\mathbb Z_3$ on the left hand side, since $-5=1$ in that ring and we can't even pick a square root of $1$ in a canonical way...It could be $1$ or $2$. If we pick $2$, the ideal is the unit ideal, hence the quotient is zero. This make no sense at all..

Comment: @AdamHughes It's called a "quotient ring", which validates terminology from fractions. So does the notation. I stand by my choice of words, although yours is just as good.

Comment: @MooS If you interpret $\Bbb Z_3[\sqrt{-5}]$ as $\Bbb Z_3[X]/(X^2+5)=\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2-1)$, with $\sqrt{-5}=X+(X^2-1)$, there is no problem at all.

Comment: There is a **huge** problem then. Because the quotient is then isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$...By the way: $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+5) = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and NOT $\mathbb Z_3[\sqrt{-5}]$. Note the $3$ in the subscript.

Comment: @MooS I meant to have a subscript. And what is the problem with using $\Bbb Z_3[\sqrt{-5}]$ as a different name for $\Bbb Z_9$?

Comment: "Dividing out" or "modding out" are both correct...and, in fact, I've heard in advanced algebra milieu more the former than the latter.

Comment: Seriously, why should I interpret $\mathbb Z_3[\sqrt{-5}]$ as something, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$, when $-5$ is already a square in $\mathbb Z_3$...By definition $\mathbb Z_3[\sqrt{-5}]$ is the smallest ring extension of $\mathbb Z_3$, thats admits a square root of $-5$. $\mathbb Z_3$ already does...

Comment: I agree with MooS: there seems to be some confusion in the question, as $\;-5=1\pmod 3\;$ , so $\;\sqrt{-5}=\sqrt1=1\;$ and then $\;\Bbb Z_3[\sqrt{-5}]=\Bbb Z_3\;$  ...

Comment: And the whole point is that even $\sqrt 1=1$ does not make sense, since there is no canonical way of picking square roots in finite fields...And it does make a hell of a difference here whether we pick $\sqrt 1=1$ or $\sqrt 1=2$...The question is so horribly posed, that I am really suprised it has not been closed yet.

Comment: @DonAntonio To me, the notation $\Bbb Z_3[\sqrt{-5}]$ can only mean a polynomial ring over $\Bbb Z_3$ in a variable that we happen to write as $\sqrt{-5}$ and which has the property that $\sqrt{-5}^2=-5$. If you have a good reason why that's not the correct interpretation, I'm more than willing to change my mind.

Comment: @Arthur That is *also* my interpetation, yet in this case (this is also for Moos), $\;\sqrt{-5}=1\,,\,2\pmod3\;$ , so in any case we get *again* $\;\Bbb Z_3\;$ back...

Comment: to all :  I made some changes in the question. There was a (killer) typo.